# JavaScript MVC vs ASP.NET MVC (Pattern Differences)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, angularjs, ember.js

### The Problem - (Back Story)

So recently I was on a few interviews and the question that was continually coming up on all four was 'Where does X reside in an MVC app?'

The problem was that the company that I was interviewing with was different each time.  Two were predominantly ASP.NET MVC / Microsoft shops and the other two were using Ext.js, Ember.js, Angular.js, or some other JavaScript MVC frameworks.

### My Answers -

**Where does business logic reside?**

*ASP.NET MVC*

In a separate layer on the server

*JavaScript MVC*

Theoretically, on or around the controllers...  **But then it's not secure...**

**Where does Validation reside?**

*ASP.NET MVC*

In the model, and the view uses it to simply alert to problems, controller validates model state before attempting to commit.

*JavaScript MVC*

Well, in the model but...  Well kinda in the view, but the controller serves it to...

### What's right?

My question is what are the differences that are supportable by facts and not opinions in where the following basic functions need to be applied in JavaScript MVC when compared to ASP.NET MVC -

#### Categories -

**Where does business logic reside?**

**Where does validation need to be applied?**

**Where does validation need to be confirmed?**

What other questions do you have to lend to this one?

Comment: I'd like to shamelessly redirect you [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145995/business-logic-in-javascript-fat-client-vs-thin-client/19570437#19570437) as I believe it's directly relevant. The short answer that you can extract from this is that no-one can possibly claim to be able to answer your question in a generic way, nor specifically without knowing what your application does. I think anyone facing this question should take a deep breath, forget about the intricacies of the web for a few minutes, and think about this at a higher level. *Let architecture be driven by your needs.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my opinion based on my experience, currently I'm working on a angularjs/servicestack app, so here we go:

There's no correct answers for these questions but I guess the best with more common sense wins :)

**Where does business logic reside?**
This basically could apply using MVC/php/Rails o any other server side programming language, since I'm using Service stack I've separated all the business operations in what I've called business services in MVC it could be the same, remember the controller no matter what framework you're using is the one that orchestrate the communication between the views and the model, I don't see why any you'll need to put any kind of logic into the controllers.

regarding to the relationship Javascript/Server framework I see the JS MVC as a client that calls my REST service (or a MVC app with a js library/ Web API, etc), the js client just sends/gets the information from the service, you can perform small client operations there but not the operations that are strictly tied to your system model, the MVC for the Js framework is more a way of separating concerns to lead TDD and DI (at least AngularJS)

**Where does validation need to be applied?**
Everywhere, the client validations suits nice since they gives instant feedback to the user, but you have to double check all the inputs in the server as well.

For me all the architecture could remain very similar in terms of how you're going to organize the layers and tiers, at the end what it changes is how you're going to present the information to the client if it's with a fancy no postback client framework or just plain views.

Just my two cents here,
I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic client side is merely convenience for the end user (and possibly performance as well).

Business logic validation doesn't "need" to be applied until you've hit the server.

Once you've hit the serve you "must" confirm/apply business logic since you can't ever truly trust an environment you don't control.

If we imagine we are Gmail for a second we can run through a few scenarios.

If the business logic is unrelated to any sort of validation, like popping up a list of people I know that I can send an email to, then it belongs client side.

If the business logic is making sure someone hasn't snuck in some sort of malicious html into their email, that validation needs to happen server side.

Malicious me can just mock an ajax call to gmail pretending I've composed an email with malicious code in the html.  But Smart Google turns around and checks the contents of the call to make sure I haven't spoofed some invalid info.